# changing first responder from uiscrollview to uitableview mid-touch iOS iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, first-responder

I have a UITableView that is added to a UIScrollView for a necessary reason.  Is it possible to switch the first responder from the uiscrollview to the uitableview after the scrollview has reached a certain contentOffset mid-touch? I tried...

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 100){
        [scrollView resignFirstResponder];
        [tableView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

But after 100, the scrollView is the one that still moves.

Comment: In general, I can tell you that this is not the way to achieve what you are looking for. If you explain the reason for this odd hierarchy, maybe we can think of some alternative implementation.

Comment: I second @stavash, please explain at a higher level what you want to accomplish. There surely is a way to achieve what you want without resorting to bad hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work that way. Once a view has been identified via `hitTest:withEvent:` to receive a touch, it will also receive all the updates for that touch and you're not able to redirect the touches without bad hacks.